# Call js function in python to use document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, getelementbyid, django-socketio

I've recently asked about a way to call a js function in python. People gave me advice such as using js2py, or pyv8, but the problem is that it does not allow me to use the following js command:

```
document.getElementById("example");
```

So my question is: Is there a way to call js from a python function and that allows you to use the js command above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If calling js function in python* means: *How can I select node with specific id?*, then you can use BeautifulSoup for it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><div id='example'></body></html>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find(id="example")
```

Comment: This actually seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help