# I am modifying code and running into errors. I am using cmd prompt in windows

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have zero experience in coding.  I worked through errors but here's the newest one:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Automate-with-Python-_-Form-Filling-Script-\myview.py", line 19, in <module>
    document.getElementById('date').value = '';
NameError: name 'document' is not defined

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Automate-with-Python-_-Form-Filling-Script->
```

I have lots of requests for elements, so Im sure it'll happen on every request I made.

Please help me identify what I need to change where it says document.get

RM

Comment: it has problem with name `document`, not with `document.get` - and it shows name `getElementById`, not `get`. it seems you never created `document`. You didn't show code so we can't help you. Frankly, it looks like `JavaScript` code, not Python, and you try to run it as Python code. And maybe this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103584/14812314

There is a similar Question
This could help you.